# how to solve error blocked by x-frame option policy

Tags: html, firefox, iframe

i am trying to insert a video from YouTube using i frame, so i copied the code from their embed link which is this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9YffrCViTVk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

its working perfectly on google chrome but on firefox its giving this error:

```
Blocked by X-Frame-Options Policy

An error occurred during a connection to www.youtube.com.

Firefox prevented this page from loading in this context because the page has an X-Frame-Options policy that disallows it.
```

[image]

any idea's thanks in advance!!!